# How I should make a bash script to run a C++ program?

Tags: bash

I have a C++ program and its command to run in linux terminal is:

```
./executable file input.txt parameter output.txt
```

I want to make a bash script for it, but I cannot. I tried this one:

```
#!/bin/bash
file_name=$(echo $1|sed 's/\(.*\)\.cpp/\1/')
g++ -o $file_name.out $1
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    ./$file_name.out
fi
```

but it is not right, because it does not get input and also numerical parameter. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script assumes the first argument is the source file name and that it's a .cpp file.  Error handling emitted for brevity.

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-O
input_file=$1
shift # pull off first arg
args="$*"
filename=${input_file%%.cpp}

$CC -o $filename.out $CFLAGS $input_file
rc=$?

if [[ $rc -eq 0 ]]; then
   ./$filename.out $args
   exit $?
fi

exit $rc
```

So, for example running the script "doit" with the arguments "myprogram.cpp input.txt parameter output.txt" we see:

```
% bash -x ./doit myprogram.cpp input.txt parameter output.txt
+ set -x
+ CC=g++
+ CFLAGS=-O
+ input_file=myprogram.cpp
+ shift
+ args='input.txt parameter output.txt'
+ filename=myprogram
+ g++ -o myprogram.out -O myprogram.cpp
+ rc=0
+ [[ 0 -eq 0 ]]
+ ./myprogram.out input.txt parameter output.txt
+ exit 0
```

Comment: and in which part of your script should I modify for my exe file, input and numerical parameter? Sorry, I am very very beginner in bash scripting.

Comment: You don't need to modify the script--it should work as is, if I understand your use case correctly.  Or do you have some other expectations?  If so, please modify your question stating more precisely what it is you would like the script to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The only thing is that since I have a makefile, then I have an exe file instead of cpp. It means my command to run the code in terminal is: ./myprogram.exe input.txt parameter output.txt .

Comment: If you have a makefile that already generates the executable, do you really need a bash script to compile the file again?